# "Interesting" problems in $NLogTime \cap coNLogTime$

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

In terms of machine model, I'm interested in multitape Turing machines with random access to the input via a query tape.

Criteria for "interesting" in this context:

- Not in $DLogTime$: "what's the length of the input" falls into this category
- Depends on the whole input: a padded decision version of Factoring is a problem in the desired class, but ignores most of the input and is just a rescaled problem in $NP \cap coNP$.
- Isn't a promise problem: "Given two lists of bits A and B, promised that exactly one of them is identically zero, is A identically zero?" is in the desired class, but is a promise problem such that the promise isn't in the desired class.

It's also very possible no such problem exists -- it might be that "any non-promise problem in $NLogTime \cap coNLogTime$ that depends on the whole input is also in $DLogTime$" -- which would also be an interesting answer.

Comment: Something possibly relevant: I know that every decision tree has both an equivalent CNF and an equivalent DNF (that are not much bigger). I believe these are the uniform counterparts of coNLogTime and NLogTime *with an oracle in NLogTime*, i.e. they are one level up the LogTime hierarchy than the ones you are asking about. Phrased otherwise, something like evaluation of a decision tree should be in $\Pi_2$-LogTime $\cap$ $\Sigma_2$-LogTime (assuming the CNF / DNF conversions go through uniformly). Perhaps some restricted form of Decision Tree might no longer need the extra NLogTime oracle.

Comment: ...but in fact, doesn't any NLogTime predicate $P$ necessarily have polynomial-size clauses, i.e.  $P(x) \iff \bigvee L^P_{|x|}$ for $L^P_{|x|}$ a set of literals depending on $|x|$ (dually, terms $\bigwedge L^Q_{|x|}$, for any coNLogTime predicate $Q$) ? If so then even $P \subseteq Q$ is equivalent to $L^P_n = L^Q_n = \{l_n\}$ for some literal $l_n$, for each $n$. It feels like the value of such $l_n$ should be readily computed in DLogTime by restricting to some/any path through an NLogTime machine for $P$ (or a coNLogTime machine for $Q$).